# How to prevent dismissing keyboard when the user did tap on the button

Tags: ios, swift

I have two UI Components in my UIViewController. a UITextField and UIButton.
When the view did load I call `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` to show the keyboard. the problem is I don't wanna dismiss the keyboard when the user taps on the button.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to implement the UITextFieldDelegate and then prevent the textfield to lose the focus implementing the method:

```
var shouldEndEditing = false

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        shouldEndEditing = true
 }

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     return shouldEndEditing
}
```

Comment: It's work but I'm looking for a better solution. now the problem is when the view controller dismissed keyboard still showing, I call ``view.endEditiing(true)`` but the keyboard doesn't dismiss.

Comment: have you tried calling textfield.resignFirstResponder when dismissing the ViewController? (eg. in viewDidDisappear or in viewWillDisappear)

Comment: yes, I called resingFirstResponder on dismissing but it doesn't work.

Comment: try to add some logic to textFieldShouldEndEditing using a Boolean variable to decide when dismiss the keyboard

Comment: Based on the document this delegate is just a recommendation however dismissing the keyboard does not happen.
[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619592-textfieldshouldendediting)

Comment: it's worked but with a little delay, the keyboard did dismiss.

Comment: the delay it's a normal behaviour when you are dismissing a VC. (thanks for the upvote)